# LaserJet 500 color M551dn drops print jobs. restart required

Tags: printing, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I am running a HP LaserJet 500 color M551dn which is connected via Ethernet. I really like the printer quality and everything is working great, except one recurring issue.

Every 2-3 weeks…

- The printer stops responding and we are unable to print from multiple computers: client OS throws the message »Connecting to Laserjet…«
  The printer is turned on and the control panel indicates it is ready.
- I am unable to load the hp web access for the LaserJet 500 to look up the printer job status.
- The printer can’t be pinged with the local ip address. It looks like the printer network or printer spool is dead (crashed?) and is not responding.
- Once the printer has been shutdown and restarted, everything is working as usual.
- Of course, laserjet uses a static ip address

I’ve followed multiple hp Knowledge Base articles as described. I am running the latest hp firmware and printer drivers.

What else can I do? Anyone experiencing the same issue? Is this is known issue? Do I really have to restart the LaserJet 500 color M551dn on regular basis?

Comment: Anyone experiencing the same issue? Is this is known issue?

Comment: No answers, so here is just a remark: This can be anything at all, hardware, software, or a hardware problem causing a software glitch, or maybe caused by something in the networked environment. HP Support is better qualified to answer such a question. I don't see anything wrong with restarting the printer every week: Windows for example is not very good at lasting more than a few days without reboot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check to see if the printer has entered sleep mode.  Usually the display panel on the printer will say "Sleep Mode" or similar.  The printer should wake up on its own once it receives print jobs, but you can wake it manually by pressing one of the menu navigation buttons physically located on the printer.  On waking, the printer should receive and start printing jobs once again.

Sleep mode settings can be changed either via the web console or physically at the printer.  Printers that are asleep may also be inaccessible via the web until waking.

2. If **NOT** using a print server, first ensure that ALL users have updated drivers.  Then, during the next failure check to see if an error is displayed on the printer's display panel during this time.  If no error, check to see if the menu can be navigated on the printer via the menu navigation buttons.  If the menu can be navigated, use the menu to print a test page.

- If an error is displayed, or if menu navigation is "frozen" - check to ensure that all users of the printer are using updated drivers.
- Additionally, provide users with the option to use PS drivers for PDF files rather than PCL drivers.
- I don't have the specific error number on hand, but I've seen issues where users who are connected via the network but **NOT** via a print server can send jobs to the printer that cause the the printer to crash.
- This usually happens with PDF files that require PS drivers to print rather than PCL drivers.
- However, I will note that a reboot of the printer normally does not resolve this issue - normally, the PC in question will continue crash the printer until the print queue on the PC is cleared out.

3. If using a print server, and if drivers have been updated, you may need to completely uninstall and then reinstall the drivers for this printer.

From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732946(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_RemoveDrivers

- To remove printer drivers
- Open Print Management.
- In the left pane, click Print Servers, click
  the applicable print server, and then click Printers.
- In the center pane, right-click those printers that use the driver that you want to delete, or change the driver that is used by each printer to another driver.
- In the left pane, click Print Servers, click the applicable print server, and then click Drivers. In the center pane, right-click the driver and do one of the following: To delete only the installed driver files, click Delete.
- To remove the driver package from the driver store, completely removing the driver from the computer, click Remove Driver Package.
- Additional considerations: To open Print Management, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Print Management.

4. Check your DHCP server to ensure that it isn't attempting to hand out the IP address that is statically assigned to the printer.   The type of network blip that results from a duplicate IP could theoretically require a printer reboot.

Based on what you described, I think Sleep Mode is the likely culprit.  Beyond the above steps, you may need to get in touch with HP support for more in-depth troubleshooting.  Good luck.

Source for all of this: providing IT support to an organization with 25+ HP printers, a few of which were the model you're working with.